# How to find if excel column has a sequence?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, numbers, match, sequence

How to find if excel column contains the sequence i am looking for?

for example column 1 contains A B C D A B B C D A B and i would like to find if the column contains A B and would like to know the row number in which it starts from. similar to the [example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPfwA.png)

I found a solution from the website http://www.get-digital-help.com/2014/10/28/find-a-sequence/? but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How is the data laid out? Is that `A B C D A B B C D A B` in a single cell, or is each letter in its own cell, going down the column? What have you tried specifically, please include your formula, and the error it returns, or the value it returns.

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne , i added a link to the snapshot of the data , please refer to it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question -- essentially, how do we use MATCH for 2 criteria, not just one. We can do this via array formulas. In essence, we're going to make a new array, that concatenates each possible combination of sequential entries (so in the example, it would look like AB,BC,CD,DA,AB,BB,BC...). Then we can search that as need be for 'AB'.

The formula looks like this:

```
=MATCH("A"&"B",A1:A100&A2:A101,0)
```

Or more generally:

```
=MATCH([Criteria 1]&[Criteria 2],[Data 1st val]:[Data last val]&[Data 2nd val]:[Data last + 1 val],0)
```

A **very important** note: after writing in the formula, do not press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This tells Excel to treat it as an array formula. If done correctly, you should see curly braces around the formula.

Comment: Thank you Robert! , i was not doing ctrl-shift-enter after the formula . 
I also found another way to do it using a formula like =IF(OR(AND(A2=$B$2,A3=$B$3 )  ),"success","") , where column a contains A B C D A B C D and column B contains the real sequence A B.