# How do I search for most similar sequence in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, match, sequence, closest

I'm hoping to search an excel column for the sequence in it most similar to a sequence I enter.

For instance, in the following example, the sequence I provide is: 1, 2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 1. It's depicted on the following graph as black.

In the column I'm searching, there are a few sequences. The most similar one to mine is colored blue. It goes: 1, 2, 3, 2, 1.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqPFZ.png)

Do any of you know an excel formula, or series of formulas and steps, that would allow Excel to determine this -- so that when I enter the black sequence, for instance, it will match it with the blue sequence as the most similar one?

Thanks to[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935880/how-to-find-if-excel-column-has-a-sequence) Stack overflow answer, I already know how to search a set of numbers for an exact sequence by using the following formula:

=MATCH([Criteria 1]&[Criteria 2],[Data 1st val]:[Data last val]&[Data 2nd val]:[Data last + 1 val],0)

For instance, if I have the following numbers: 1, 3, 5, 1, 4, and I am hoping to find the sequence, 1, 4, this formula will direct me towards it in that set of numbers.

I ALSO already know how to find the closest match to a number I enter, using this formula (which will make more sense if you look in the example image below): =INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(MIN(ABS(C1-B1:B10)),ABS(C1-$B$1:$B$10),0))

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xNA1.png)

When I press control+shift+enter, this formula will produce the number 4, indicating row 4, because the number I entered in C1, which was 39, is closest to the number 40, which is located in the 4th row.

So I have both the components -- finding exact sequences, and finding the closest number -- but now the question is, how do I *combine* these two formulas to show me the *closest sequence of numbers*, the one which would look most similar if drawn on a graph like in my first example with the blue and black line?

And bonus points if you can help find not only the closest sequence but the closest *sequences* in order of most similar to least similar.

And once again, I don't need this to be rolled into one formula; I am happy to go through a couple steps and different formulas manually to arrive at the answer.

And if you think this would be better solved in some other way, please let me know! But I do not have any coding experience so I figured Excel would be my best bet.

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you exactly have set this up, but if I visualize your graph in a table you could use the below (if one has Microsoft365):

[image]

Formula in `H2`:

```
=INDEX(SORTBY(B2:F4,MMULT(ABS(B2:F4-B1:F1),SEQUENCE(5,,,0))),1)
```

---

With all your data in a single column, below you can find an example for if you'd have sequences of 5.

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(SORTBY(INDEX(A2:A16,SEQUENCE(11,5)-ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(11,5,0,0.2),0)*4),MMULT(ABS(INDEX(A2:A16,SEQUENCE(11,5)-ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(11,5,0,0.2),0)*4)-TRANSPOSE(B2:B6)),SEQUENCE(5,,,0))),1))
```

---

If you would want to make this applicable for your dataset from `A1:A500` with sequence of 10 numbers:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(SORTBY(INDEX(A1:A500,SEQUENCE(COUNT(A1:A500)-9,10)-ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(COUNT(A1:A500)-9,10,0,0.1),0)*9),MMULT(ABS(INDEX(A1:A500,SEQUENCE(COUNT(A1:A500)-9,10)-ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(COUNT(A1:A500)-9,10,0,0.1),0)*9)-TRANSPOSE(B1:B10)),SEQUENCE(10,,,0))),1))
```

And if will be even better if you had acces to `LET()` and it will be a piece of cake to just change the range reference:

```
=LET(X,A2:A500,Y,INDEX(X,SEQUENCE(COUNT(X)-9,10)-ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(COUNT(X)-9,10,0,0.1),0)*9),TRANSPOSE(INDEX(SORTBY(Y,MMULT(ABS(Y-TRANSPOSE(B2:B11)),SEQUENCE(10,,,0))),1)))
```

---

**EDIT2:**

To make it more dynamic you can use:

```
=LET(W,1,X,A2:A500,Y,11,Z,INDEX(X,SEQUENCE(COUNT(X)-(Y-1),Y)-ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(COUNT(X)-(Y-1),Y,0,1/Y),0)*(Y-1)),TRANSPOSE(INDEX(SORTBY(Z,MMULT(ABS(Z-TRANSPOSE(B2:INDEX(B:B,Y+1))),SEQUENCE(Y,,,0))),W)))
```

Where "W" is the nth closest match and where "Y" is the length of the sequence, 11 in the example.

Comment: Hi JvdV, you are a genius! This is my first time using Stack Overflow, and it feels too good to be true. THANK YOU, this brings me much closer to my goal! However, there is one more piece of the problem I would love your help on: In this case, there are three independent sequences (orange, blue, and grey). However, in my case, there will simply be one long column of numbers, like A1:A500. And in that set of numbers, there are around 500 10-number sequences: A1:A10 , A2:A11 , A3:A12 , and so on. Is there any way to apply your MMULT formula to these sequences within one column?

Comment: Maybe it's wise to first write out all possible sequences of ten using `=INDEX(A$2:A$500,SEQUENCE(1,10,ROW(A1)))`. Drag this down untill the last sequence and then use the above solution.

Comment: Hi JvdV, this is amazing and exactly what I was looking for. I'm having great success with the LET () formula up to the number 10. However -- and I'm so sorry to keep asking questions -- when I try to go higher, it says #ref. If I wanted to look for sequences 30, or 45 numbers long, would you mind explaining how I should enter them into the formula? This is what I have for 11, which isn't working. =LET(X,A1:A15000,Y,INDEX(X,SEQUENCE(COUNT(X)-10,11)-ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(COUNT(X)-10,11,0,0.1),0)*9),TRANSPOSE(INDEX(SORTBY(Y,MMULT(ABS(Y-TRANSPOSE(B1:B11)),SEQUENCE(11,,,0))),1)))    --Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, and one more tiny thing -- and then I promise, I'm done, because you've gone above and beyond-- do you know of a way to make it provide not just the closest match, but the second closest, third closest, etc. as well? So far I've been able to find them by simply deleting the closest match from the set of numbers, and then it automatically goes to the next best option, but there must be a better way. Thank you so much for all of this -- you are both kind and incredibly smart

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly what I was looking for. How do you know all this stuff?? Either way, thank you so much -- this makes a huge impact on my life

Comment: It's a simple matter of interest in the mechanics behind these combined functions. See it as a puzzle. I love puzzle's @helpless99

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to calculate a match-value between each color and the input values, like the sum of the differences for each point.

The formula for this is:

```
=SUM(IF([inputrange]<>"",ABS([inputrange]-[colorrange]),0))
```

Where [inputrange] is the range of your input (indicated red in the picture below, $C$6:$G$6) and [colorrange] is the range of that color (indicated blue, C2:G2).

[image]

The color with the lowest difference is the match:

```
=VLOOKUP(MIN([matchvalues],[rangeofmatchandcolors],2,0)
```

Where [matchvalues] is the range of match values (indicated blue in the picture below, Cells A2:A4) and [rangeofmatchandcolors] is both the match values as well as the colors (indicated red, A2:B4)
**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks so much for answering my question. This looks really interesting, and my favorite feature is the match value numbers on the side, because it will make it easy for me not only to find the closest match, but the second closest, third closest, etc. as well. However, I unfortunately find myself too dumb to figure out how to enter the formulas. I'm not sure what you mean by, "Where [inputrange] is the point values of your input (black) and [colorrange] is the range of that color." Would you be able to give an example with the formula filled in for one of the colors? Thank you!!!

Comment: I've updated the answer with more details. The images correspond to the formula entered  above it

Comment: Ah, that helped a lot -- clearly, I'm a beginner, which I hope isn't too frustrating to deal with. But I've got it up and running now thanks to your detailed instructions. Now, however, I must tell you the ugly truth: my data is not in individual sequences, such as gray, blue, and orange. Really, it's simply in one long column of numbers, like A1:A500. And in that set of numbers, there are around 500 10-number sequences: A1:A10 , A2:A11 , A3:A12 , and so on. Is there any way to apply your awesome formula to these sequences within one column?

Comment: To not only extract the closest sequence (which the above user has already figured out), but to provide a match value for every sequence? That way, I can order the match values from smallest to largest, so that I can see the most similar sequence, the second most similar sequence, the third most similar sequence, etc. Thank you so incredibly much for taking the time! You're truly amazing.

Comment: It can be the same formula, only for a different set of ranges. As long as the amount of cells in each range (the sections between the [ ] in my example) is the same, you're good to go. In your example, a color had 5 data points, so that's why I use column C through G. For instance, you can put the matching value formula next to every number. If you think of every number as the start of a sequence, you're effectively removing the color names from this equation. The lowest matching value shows you the start point (first number) of the best match

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you so much for sticking through this with me! So kind of you to take time out of your day for a random internet stranger. It's hugely helped me.