# Adding criterea to find matching sequence

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sequence, lookup

I have a meal planning spreadsheet that calculates daily meal macros. I have a food list with 4 macros and I would like to find the food that best matches the macros from a target sequence.

I am able to get the closest matching sequence from this thread: [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490076/how-do-i-search-for-most-similar-sequence-in-excel](https://stackoverflow.com)], but two additional criterea might be needed.

I was able to find matching foods, macro by macro, with this formula, but it doesn't match sequence by sequence: =INDEX($A$2:$A$200;EQUIV(MIN(ABS($C$2:$C$200-$K$4));ABS($C$2:$C$200-$K$4);0))

I was able to calculate the spread of the sequence with this formula: =SUM(IF($I$3:$L$3<>"";ABS($I$3:$L$3-$D2:$G2);0))

I was able to find the match to the closest sequence with this formula:
=VLOOKUP(MIN(A2:A144);A2:B144;2;0)
[example spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zLu5.png)

What I can't find how to do is:

1-prioritize macros with largest spread without going over the total calories (or at least by not more than 5)
2-less important, search by matching food category

I do have access to the LET function if needed
My formulas are translate from French, so hopefully I got the function names right

| CALCUL | Name | Cat | Calories | Protein | Carbs | Fat |  | Calories | Protein | Carbs | Fat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | Orange | snack | 90 | 2 | 22 | 0 |  | 86,58 | 15,15 | 40,35 | -11,31 |
| 50 | Chobani Non-fat Plai | snack | 90 | 16 | 6 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 50 | Pear | snack | 96 | 0,63 | 25,66 | 0,2 |  | Category | snack |  |  |
| 54 | Ezekiel bread | ingr | 80 | 4 | 15 | 0 |  | Suggestion | =VLOOKUP(MIN(A2:A144),A2:B144,2,0) |  |  |
| 57 | Turkey Deli Slices | ingr | 81 | 14,4 | 2,7 | 1,7 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 58 | Brussel Sprout cook | veg | 88 | 3,95 | 11,06 | 4,43 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 59 | Pangasius poached | ingr | 90 | 17 | 0 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: How do you determine the closest match? The difference in proteins, fats, sugars are to be treated equally?

Comment: I was hoping to give priority to the largest spread first. So if the spread for instance on Carbs is much larger than the spread on Fats, it would look for the closest Carbs match first. I really couldn't think of how to do that, but I think it might be OK without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this in a new sheet:

| CALCUL | Name | Cat | Calories | Proteins | Carbs | Fats |  | Category | Calories | Proteins | Carbs | Fats |  |  |  | Index | Name | Cat | Calories | Proteins | Carbs | Fat |  |  | Cat | Calories | Delta proteins multiplied | Delta carbs multiplied | Delta fats multiplied | Total difference |  | Min difference | Match |  |  | Name | Cat | Calories | Proteins | Carbs | Fat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | Orange | snack | 90 | 2 | 22 | 0 |  | ingr | 90 | 10 | 5 | 0 |  |  | =ROWS($P$2:P2)&"° suggestion" | `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/((ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q2))),1)` | =INDEX(B:B,$Q2) | =INDEX(C:C,$Q2) | =INDEX(D:D,$Q2) | =INDEX(E:E,$Q2) | =INDEX(F:F,$Q2) | =INDEX(G:G,$Q2) |  |  | =IF(OR($I$2="",C2=$I$2),IF(C2="","",C2),"") | =IF(AND(D2<=$J$2,D2<>0),D2,"") | =ABS(E2-$K$2)*$K$5 | =ABS(F2-$L$2)*$L$5 | =ABS(G2-$M$2)*$M$5 | =IF(OR(Z2="",AA2=""),"",SUM(AB2:AD2)) |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,AE:AE,ROWS($AG$2:AG2)) | =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(AE:AE)/(AE:AE=AG2),COUNTIF($AG$2:AG2,AG2)) |  | =ROWS($AJ$2:AJ2)&"° suggestion" | =INDEX(B:B,$AH2) | =INDEX(C:C,$AH2) | =INDEX(D:D,$AH2) | =INDEX(E:E,$AH2) | =INDEX(F:F,$AH2) | =INDEX(G:G,$AH2) |
| 50 | Chobani Non-fat Plai | snack | 90 | 16 | 6 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =ROWS($P$2:P3)&"° suggestion" | `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/((ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q3))),1)` | =INDEX(B:B,$Q3) | =INDEX(C:C,$Q3) | =INDEX(D:D,$Q3) | =INDEX(E:E,$Q3) | =INDEX(F:F,$Q3) | =INDEX(G:G,$Q3) |  |  | =IF(OR($I$2="",C3=$I$2),IF(C3="","",C3),"") | =IF(AND(D3<=$J$2,D3<>0),D3,"") | =ABS(E3-$K$2)*$K$5 | =ABS(F3-$L$2)*$L$5 | =ABS(G3-$M$2)*$M$5 | =IF(OR(Z3="",AA3=""),"",SUM(AB3:AD3)) |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,AE:AE,ROWS($AG$2:AG3)) | =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(AE:AE)/(AE:AE=AG3),COUNTIF($AG$2:AG3,AG3)) |  | =ROWS($AJ$2:AJ3)&"° suggestion" | =INDEX(B:B,$AH3) | =INDEX(C:C,$AH3) | =INDEX(D:D,$AH3) | =INDEX(E:E,$AH3) | =INDEX(F:F,$AH3) | =INDEX(G:G,$AH3) |
| 50 | Pear | snack | 96 | 0,63 | 25,66 | 0,2 |  |  |  | Proteins | Carbs | Fat |  |  | =ROWS($P$2:P4)&"° suggestion" | `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/((ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q4))),1)` | =INDEX(B:B,$Q4) | =INDEX(C:C,$Q4) | =INDEX(D:D,$Q4) | =INDEX(E:E,$Q4) | =INDEX(F:F,$Q4) | =INDEX(G:G,$Q4) |  |  | =IF(OR($I$2="",C4=$I$2),IF(C4="","",C4),"") | =IF(AND(D4<=$J$2,D4<>0),D4,"") | =ABS(E4-$K$2)*$K$5 | =ABS(F4-$L$2)*$L$5 | =ABS(G4-$M$2)*$M$5 | =IF(OR(Z4="",AA4=""),"",SUM(AB4:AD4)) |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,AE:AE,ROWS($AG$2:AG4)) | =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(AE:AE)/(AE:AE=AG4),COUNTIF($AG$2:AG4,AG4)) |  | =ROWS($AJ$2:AJ4)&"° suggestion" | =INDEX(B:B,$AH4) | =INDEX(C:C,$AH4) | =INDEX(D:D,$AH4) | =INDEX(E:E,$AH4) | =INDEX(F:F,$AH4) | =INDEX(G:G,$AH4) |
| 54 | Ezekiel bread | ingr | 80 | 17 | 0 | 2 |  |  | Weights | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =IF(OR($I$2="",C5=$I$2),IF(C5="","",C5),"") | =IF(AND(D5<=$J$2,D5<>0),D5,"") | =ABS(E5-$K$2)*$K$5 | =ABS(F5-$L$2)*$L$5 | =ABS(G5-$M$2)*$M$5 | =IF(OR(Z5="",AA5=""),"",SUM(AB5:AD5)) |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,AE:AE,ROWS($AG$2:AG5)) | =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(AE:AE)/(AE:AE=AG5),COUNTIF($AG$2:AG5,AG5)) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 57 | Turkey Deli Slices | ingr | 81 | 14,4 | 2,7 | 1,7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =IF(OR($I$2="",C6=$I$2),IF(C6="","",C6),"") | =IF(AND(D6<=$J$2,D6<>0),D6,"") | =ABS(E6-$K$2)*$K$5 | =ABS(F6-$L$2)*$L$5 | =ABS(G6-$M$2)*$M$5 | =IF(OR(Z6="",AA6=""),"",SUM(AB6:AD6)) |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,AE:AE,ROWS($AG$2:AG6)) | =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(AE:AE)/(AE:AE=AG6),COUNTIF($AG$2:AG6,AG6)) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 58 | Brussel Sprout cook | veg | 88 | 3,95 | 11,06 | 4,4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =IF(OR($I$2="",C7=$I$2),IF(C7="","",C7),"") | =IF(AND(D7<=$J$2,D7<>0),D7,"") | =ABS(E7-$K$2)*$K$5 | =ABS(F7-$L$2)*$L$5 | =ABS(G7-$M$2)*$M$5 | =IF(OR(Z7="",AA7=""),"",SUM(AB7:AD7)) |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,AE:AE,ROWS($AG$2:AG7)) | =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(AE:AE)/(AE:AE=AG7),COUNTIF($AG$2:AG7,AG7)) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 59 | Pangasius poached | ingr | 90 | 17 | 0 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =IF(OR($I$2="",C8=$I$2),IF(C8="","",C8),"") | =IF(AND(D8<=$J$2,D8<>0),D8,"") | =ABS(E8-$K$2)*$K$5 | =ABS(F8-$L$2)*$L$5 | =ABS(G8-$M$2)*$M$5 | =IF(OR(Z8="",AA8=""),"",SUM(AB8:AD8)) |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,AE:AE,ROWS($AG$2:AG8)) | =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(AE:AE)/(AE:AE=AG8),COUNTIF($AG$2:AG8,AG8)) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =IF(OR($I$2="",C9=$I$2),IF(C9="","",C9),"") | =IF(AND(D9<=$J$2,D9<>0),D9,"") | =ABS(E9-$K$2)*$K$5 | =ABS(F9-$L$2)*$L$5 | =ABS(G9-$M$2)*$M$5 | =IF(OR(Z9="",AA9=""),"",SUM(AB9:AD9)) |  | =AGGREGATE(15,6,AE:AE,ROWS($AG$2:AG9)) | =AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(AE:AE)/(AE:AE=AG9),1) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Respectively:

- **Range A:G:** the partial data table you've provided;
- **Range I1:M2:** the stats to be matched;
- **Range J4:M5:** the weights (as in artificial neural networks) for the differences in stats;
- **Range P1:W4:** the single-formula solution (the formula is in cell Q2);
- **Range Z1:AP9:** the range-based solution;

Since your Excel is not in english, formulas won't work as they are now. You can use this subroutine to convert the values you've pasted into working formulas:

```
Sub SubValueToFormula()
    
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim RngSector As Range
    
    Set RngSector = Range("A1:AP9")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    For Each RngCell In RngSector.Cells
        
        RngCell.Value2 = RngCell.Formula
        
    Next
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
    
End Sub
```

Both methods follows the same logic:

1. pick the elements in the list accordingly to the category specified (cell I2); if no category is specified, all the elements are considered;
2. among them, pick those who have an equal or less amount of calories specified (cell J2);
3. among them, calculate the absolute difference in proteins, carbs and fats to the values specified (range K2:M2);
4. multiplies said differences by their corrisponding weights (as in an artificial neural network) specified (range K5:M5);
5. sum said multiplied differences;
6. among them, find the *n* lower value;
7. return the corrisponding row;

The range-based solution is easier to read. Then again, you can use this reduced version if you want to see the formula in action step by step:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$9)/((ABS($E$1:$E$9-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F$1:$F$9-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G$1:$G$9-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C$1:$C$9=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D$1:$D$9<=$J$2)/($D$1:$D$9>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E$1:$E$9-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F$1:$F$9-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G$1:$G$9-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C$1:$C$9=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D$1:$D$9<=$J$2)/($D$1:$D$9>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q2))),1)
```

Now, to be meticulous, the single-formula solution as it is can't report any draw correcly (it will return the first draw result *n* times). A single-formula solution if possible would be much more complicated with Excel 2016 (the one i have). To correcly report any draw, we might use a two-cell solution:

| CALCUL | Name | Cat | Calories | Proteins | Carbs | Fats |  | Category | Calories | Proteins | Carbs | Fats |  |  |  | Index | Index corrected | Name | Cat | Calories | Proteins | Carbs | Fats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | Orange | snack | 90 | 2 | 22 | 0 |  | ingr | 90 | 10 | 5 | 0 |  |  | =ROWS($P$2:P2)&"° suggestion" | `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/((ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q2))),1)` | `=IF(Q2=Q1,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/((ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q2))),COUNTIF(Q$1:Q2,Q2)),Q2)` | =INDEX(B:B,$R2) | =INDEX(C:C,$R2) | =INDEX(D:D,$R2) | =INDEX(E:E,$R2) | =INDEX(F:F,$R2) | =INDEX(G:G,$R2) |
| 50 | Chobani Non-fat Plai | snack | 90 | 16 | 6 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | =ROWS($P$2:P3)&"° suggestion" | `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/((ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q3))),1)` | `=IF(Q3=Q2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/((ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q3))),COUNTIF(Q$1:Q3,Q3)),Q3)` | =INDEX(B:B,$R3) | =INDEX(C:C,$R3) | =INDEX(D:D,$R3) | =INDEX(E:E,$R3) | =INDEX(F:F,$R3) | =INDEX(G:G,$R3) |
| 50 | Pear | snack | 96 | 0,63 | 25,66 | 0,2 |  |  |  | Protein | Carbs | Fat |  |  | =ROWS($P$2:P4)&"° suggestion" | `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/((ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q4))),1)` | `=IF(Q4=Q3,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A:$A)/((ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0)=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ABS($E:$E-$K$2)*$K$5+ABS($F:$F-$L$2)*$L$5+ABS($G:$G-$M$2)*$M$5)/(($C:$C=$I$2)+($I$2=""))/($D:$D<=$J$2)/($D:$D>0),ROWS($Q$2:Q4))),COUNTIF(Q$1:Q4,Q4)),Q4)` | =INDEX(B:B,$R4) | =INDEX(C:C,$R4) | =INDEX(D:D,$R4) | =INDEX(E:E,$R4) | =INDEX(F:F,$R4) | =INDEX(G:G,$R4) |
| 54 | Ezekiel bread | ingr | 80 | 17 | 0 | 2 |  |  | Weights | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 57 | Turkey Deli Slices | ingr | 81 | 14,4 | 2,7 | 1,7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 58 | Brussel Sprout cook | veg | 88 | 17 | 0 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 59 | Pangasius poached | ingr | 90 | 17 | 0 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Thank you for tackling such a complicated case. I've copied the above into a new sheet. I then went through the formulas to put the translated function names and replaced all the commas with ; (because decimals in French are commas, so in the formulas, they use ;). I'm getting a lot of #NUMBER and #VALUE errors, as well as a #REF error. I wanted to add a picture to show you, but I haven't found how to attach a picture to my comment.

Comment: I was just able to correct one of the problems, it was that when I copied over the table, for some reason, all references to row 2 were changed to row 1. The solution in column Q seems to give an excellent result.